# How to convert Password field to required in checkout of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, required

I want to convert password field to required from optional. I didn't found any settings to do that. Is any code available to do that?

Please help.

Comment: Do you mean you need to required customer login before checkout?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, If customer have account then login otherwise it will create account. As I am using Amasty Onestepcheckout So Password and Confirm Password option appears but they are optional only.

Comment: Best option for you is that, disable Guest checkout, so customer must need to register or login before reaching to checkout.